# remove or hide Link Relationship (XFN) form Menus tab

Tags: customization, menus, navigation, links

I'm looking for how hide or remove Link Relationship (XFN) from Menus tab (In red on the picture below)

[image]

Comment: On the top right of the menu screen you can find Screen Options where you can hide it

Comment: Thanks. But i want it to be permenant for all users with out go to the top screen each time a new users is created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some research and I don't think there are options to remove these "advanced screen options". You can however [remove the entire screen options tab](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/25034/how-to-remove-screen-options-and-help-links-in-the-admin-area) . If you really want to remove just that option you should be able to do it with css or jquery to hide/remove the options.

## jQuery solution

place the following in your functions.php

```
function abc_load_scripts_on_admin() {

    $screen = get_current_screen();

    if( $screen->ID == 'nav-menus' ) {

        wp_enqueue_script( 'abc_remove_xfn', get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). '/remove_xfn.js' );
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'abc_load_scripts_on_admin' );
```

create a file in your theme with the name remove_xfn.js.

Add the following jQuery to newly created file

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function() {

   jQuery( '#xfn-hide' ).parent().remove();
   jQuery( '.field-xfn' ).remove();
});
```

this removes both the xfn option in the screen settings and the actual setting for each menu item if its somehow turned on.

I also found the plugin [Adminize](https://wordpress.org/plugins/adminimize/) wich might do what you want but I haven't tried it yet.

Answer (score 0):

In Menu Section On Top Bar Screen Option, there is Option to Hide or Show Link Relationship Tab. Please Check Below Screenshot

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But i want it to be permenant for all users without go to the top screen each time a new users is created.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide field using jquery, put below code into your functions.php file. Also, You can hide other field using the same function to modification some changes.

```
function customize_nav_menu_screen_option() { 
?>
<script>
    jQuery( document ).ready( function() {

   jQuery( '#xfn-hide' ).parent().remove();
   jQuery( '.field-xfn' ).remove();
});
</script>
<?php
}
add_action( 'admin_footer','customize_nav_menu_screen_option' );
```